# How should multiple projects be managed in Qt Creator?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, projects-and-solutions, qmake

I have an exe that depends on multiple static libs and in visual studio, they are all managed as part of 1 sln file and the exe has dependencies on the static libs.

How can this be set up in Qt Creator?  Seems like there are 2 options:
1. create multiple projects in a Qt Creator "session". But a session is not shared among users, right? so i'm not sure how that would work?  For example, is there a session file that gets created?
2. use subprojects. and make the static lib sub projs of the exe?

Any recommendations?  I'm totally new to Qt Creator and need to use it for a linux port.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `qmake` to produce a nice `.sln` with subprojects, make one main `.pro` file with the `subdirs` template, and set the necessary dependencies of each project on another.

QtCreator uses `qmake` behind the scenes to generate a makefile and build from that, but you can also produce VS solution files by running

```
qmake ../path/to/source -tp vc
```

You can also use the Qt Visual Studio add-in to GUI-ify the process.

---

Also: to make sure the executable is relinked each time a dependant static lib is changed, use

```
CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
    LIBSUFFIX = d
    win32:LIBS += -L../staticlib1/debug
    win32:PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../staticlib1/debug/libAmbrosiad.a
} else {
    LIBSUFFIX =
    win32:LIBS += -L../staticlib1/release
    win32:PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../staticlib1/release/libAmbrosia.a
}
unix:LIBS += -L ../libAmbrosia
unix:PRE_TARGETDEPS += ../libAmbrosia/libAmbrosia$${LIBSUFFIX}.a
```

Place something like this in your executable's `.pro` file, with the note that the LIBSUFFIX part is completely optional, but in line with how Qt itself is built, so that's what I use too. Mind the "release" and "debug" subdirectories absent on Linux/Mac builds. And to be complete: the rather verbose `if-else` condition is `The Right Way (TM)` to differentiate `debug` from `release` builds in qmake project files. Simpler ways may break under several circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to do the reverse and make .pro files from a VS sln. I have not seen anything to do that though. I may need to write something of the sort. Anyway, it sounds like you're saying that the subdirs template is the way to go in general so the static libs will be subdirs of the exe project.

Comment: @glutz: Yes, the inverse may not be automated (although you could try the Visual Studio Qt add-in, it might get the basics right for you). You will have one `subdirs` `.pro`-file, which will have subdirs for each static library, *and for the exe*.

Comment: apparently my main confusion was that i wasnt setting the TEMPLATE until after i created the static lib. so the project mgr never gave me a chance to add the lib to the exe project.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the session files are created in `~/.config/Nokia/qtcreator`, the extension is `qws`, but I think this is not a really suitable solution for multiple users.

Comment: Right. i'm not clear on why sessions exist if they are not intended to be shared among users.  It seems like a mix of project structure and local user settings.  Shouldn't that be 2 separate features like VS uses .sln (shared) ans .suo (local).